dll vector intialisation with ctypes data
I want translate data from python to c++ dll library to work with matrix and then get data back. I create (c_double * 102)(c_double(0)) array in python (first and second member of array talks about matrix size).
From python i have correct data (checked by easier function, like sum of arrays member and return it), but when i try to fill matrix, it always fills by zeroes.
(python code):
In python I have class, which translate list(list()) to (c_types * 102)(0) for connection with my dll, and its kinda works correctly. Also i use pointers to transit data
class tu_matrix:
    body = (c_double * 102)(c_double(0))
    ptr = POINTER(c_double * 102)

    def load(self, data = list(list())):
        self.data = data
        self.n_size = len(data)
        self.m_size = len(data[0])
        for i in range(self.n_size):
            for j in range(self.m_size):
                self.body[2+i*self.m_size + j] = c_double(data[i][j])
        ptr = pointer(self.body)


def calcMatrix():
    tu_matrix1.load(matrix1)
    tu_matrix2.load(matrix2)

    # Args for matrix_sum
    matrix_lib.matrix_sum.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double * 102), 
                                      POINTER(c_double * 102)]  

    # Return type of matrix_sum
    matrix_lib.matrix_sum.restype = POINTER(c_double * 102) 

    # Получение указателей на массивы
    ptr1 = pointer(tu_matrix1.send())  # first array pointer
    ptr2 = pointer(tu_matrix2.send())  # second array pointer

    # Вызов функции, передающей массивы
    result_ptr = matrix_lib.matrix_sum(ptr1, ptr2)

    result_array = result_ptr.contents  # get content from pointer

    # translation to list
    list_of_lists = []
    for i in range(0, 102, 10):  
        sublist = [result_array[i + j] for j in range(10) if i + j < 102]
        list_of_lists.append(sublist)

    print(list_of_lists)

    return result_ptr

(function to convert data):
In my C++ code I fill vector with data from python and in this moment catch error whith not correct data. Its all in zeroes, when i try to use, i think that problem whith personal class, because simple arrays or data types works ok.
template<typename val_type>
void matrix<val_type>::arr_to_matrix(double arr[102]) {

    this->body.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)arr[0]; i++) {
        vector<double> line;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)arr[1]; j++) {
            // vec[i][m] = arr[i * m + j];
            line.push_back(arr[2 + i * (int)arr[1] + j]);
        }
        this->body.push_back(line);
    }

    this->size_n = (int)arr[0];
    this->size_m = (int)arr[1];
    this->empty_matrix = false;
    this->zero_matrix = false;
    this->was_calc_det = false;
}

(dll function):
static double result[102];

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double* matrix_sum(double arr1[102], double arr2[102]) {
    // Sum of matrix for python c-types data
    matrix<double> m1({ { 1,1 }, { 2,2 } });
    matrix<double> m2({ { 1,1 }, { 2,2 } });

    m1.arr_to_matrix(arr1);
    m2.arr_to_matrix(arr2);

    m1 += m2;

    int n = m1.line_size();
    int m = m1.column_size();

    result[0] = n;
    result[1] = m;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            result[2 + i * m + j] = m1.val(i, j);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

If i delete strings m1.arr_to_matrix(arr1); m2.arr_to_matrix(arr2); it will init by initlist and works correct, but in that case the whole point of creating a python interface is lost. When i run programm without python and check, it works correctly:
(it works)
int main () {
    double* arr1 = new double[102];
    double* arr2 = new double[102];

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        arr1[i] = 2;
        arr2[i] = 2;
    }

    arr1 = matrix_sum(arr1, arr2);

    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        std::cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }

}


Please make a [mcve]. Include imports and ensure the Python and C++ code can be copy/paste/run without changes to reproduce the problem.  Although the code is incomplete, it appears the size of the matrix isn't added to self.body, e.g. self.body[0] = self.n_size and self.body[1] = self.m_size so the C++ code thinks the matrix size is 0x0.

I feel both stupid and good at the same time. I actually forgot in the python part to set the size identifiers in the first two elements of the ctypes-array. Thanks)
